# CSRF in laravel 5.8 with axios and vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have a doubt, I'm using Laravel 5.8 and I have a component in Vue that is a simple registration form. When I submit the form via POST method, Laravel doesn't request me the CSRF token, is this a normal behavior? I'm not using the API routes.

I just noticed in the Chrome storage there is a XSRF-TOKEN.

[image]

So, how is now working the CSRF validation via ajax?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

as mentioned in the `laravel5.8` doc

> When building JavaScript driven applications, it is convenient to have
>   your JavaScript HTTP library automatically attach the CSRF token to
>   every outgoing request. By default, the  resources/js/bootstrap.js
>   file registers the value of the csrf-token meta tag with the Axios
>   HTTP library. If you are not using this library, you will need to
>   manually configure this behavior for your application

for more information check [laravel 5.8 csrf doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf)

.